# Prove $A\cap (X \setminus A) =\emptyset$ and $(A\cap B)\cap C=A\cap (B\cap C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, solution-verification

Where $A$,$B$,$C$ are sets and $X$ is a set containing $A$ as a subset.

Both of these are from Proposition $3.1.27$  on Tao's Analysis I. These are the only proofs where I feel like I might've made a mistake in my logic because I'm rather inexperienced.

For the first I tried proving that every element $x$ in $A\cap (X\setminus A)$ is also an element of $\emptyset$ and vice versa. First suppose that $x\in \emptyset$ then the conclusion $x\in A\cap (X\setminus A)$ is vacuously true. Now suppose that $x \in A\cap (X\setminus A)$. Then $x \in A $ and $x\in X\setminus A \iff x \in A \text{ and } x\in \{y \in X: y\notin A\} \iff x\in A \text{ and } (x\in X \text{ and } x\notin A) $. Since we have $x\in A$ and $x \notin A$, the conclusion $x \in \emptyset$ is vacuously true.

For the second I tried proving it again by saying: We need to show that every element $x$ in $(A\cap B)\cap C$ is also an element of $A\cap (B\cap C)$ and vice versa; but I ended up proving an equivalance. Suppose $x \in (A\cap B)\cap C \iff (x\in A\cap b) \land (x\in C)\iff ((x\in A) \land (x\in B))\land (x \in C)\iff (x\in A)\land(x\in B)\land(x \in C) \iff (x\in A)\land((x\in B)\land(x\in C))\iff x\in A\cap(B\cap C)$.

So, both of these proofs kind of rely on the fact that $x\in A$ and $(x \in B \text{ and } x\in C)$ is the same as the statement $x\in A$ and $x \in B$ and $x\in C$. But this feels artificial. For the second proof I had the thought that set $\cap$ symbol has the same logic indentities as "and" so reducing the problem to logic made the solution trivial to the extent that it doesn't feel like a proof. I'm basically proving associativity of intersection by using the associativity of logic. But since the same logic applies to both symbols this seems like a non-proof.

To be clear, I'm not really interested in a new proof of these since I can do both of those in a more standard way that I'm pretty sure is correct. I want to know why these proofs do or don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is something I grappled with when working through Tao's analysis as well. This is the reasoning that I came down to accept in the end:

First a comment on the first proof: I don't fully understand your reasoning. The first inclusion is trivial as the emptyset is a subset of every set as you also point out. Suppose now $x \in A \cap (X \backslash A)$. Then, $x \in A$ and $x \in X \backslash A$. However, from here on I am not sure to follow your reasoning. Wouldn't it be easier to simply state that $x \in X \backslash A$ corresponds to that element which is in $X$ but not $A$; i.e., $x \in X \wedge x \notin A$. Thus we have $x \in A$ and $x \notin A$ which is already a contradiction? To be clear you might be stating this, but it wasn't clear to me how.

On to the second bit. I think the proof is corect and I do agree. There is a sense in which the associativity of $\cap$ boils down to the associativity of $\wedge$ and this might or might not feel artificial. However, this is essentially correct. Furthermore, you can prove this without ever writing down the logical symbol $\wedge$ as Tao does in some exercise, if I'm not wrong, and simply rely on words and the more intuitive meaning of words and sets. So that "something and something else" must be equivalent to "somthing else and something" by pure means of logic. This is also what, I think he tries to explain in the appendix A on mathemtical logic; i.e., to really understand these concepts rather than learn the rules; e.g., associativity of $\wedge$.

PS: Thinking about this more, I think that the issue comes in by mixing parts of the proof in plain English and part in first order logic. One should feel confortable to manipulate the ideas in both forms. In this case Tao seems to privilige the use of plain english and a more intuitive reliance on logic rather than a pure symbol manipulation. Obviosuly the two are equivalent, but the feeling of ariticiality might arise precisely because there is a mix of the two.

Comment: I'll think about the second bit a bit more. I haven't actually given a full read through his appendix on logic because his choice of using only the english language and me trying to translate it to symbols gave me a bit of a headache. I actually like that he doesn't use symbols for the most part but I've still not completely digested it.

Comment: @Eric I think this is precisely what caused confusion to me as well. If you have already familiarity with a pure symbol manipulation approach you might benefit to follow Tao's approach in full. Just to see how it plays out and perhaps, dispell some of that artificiality you might feel.

Comment: For the first, that was the part of the proof that seemed a bit off to me. But my thought process was that since we assumed something that can't be true, much like assuming $x\in \emptyset$, then every conclusion we make must be true and thus we can say that $x \in \emptyset$.

Comment: @Eric In words, the first part would be: suppose $x \in A \cap (X \backslash A)$. Thus, $x \in A$ and $x \in X \backslash A$. Since $x \in X \backslash A$, then $x$ must be in $X$ and it must not be in $A$. However, this contradicts the fact that $x \in A$ just like $x \in \emptyset$ is a contradiction.

Comment: Is my way not correct then? Because getting a contradiction was my first thought but I wasn't sure how to conclude that since we have a contradiction then, $x\in \emptyset$. So that was my way of dealing with this, using vacuous truth. I think we are saying pretty much the same thing here but I may be wrong.

Comment: @Eric I think the best way to put it is the following: Suppose towards contradiction that there exists an $x \in A \cap (X \backslash A)$. Then, ... bla bla, same proof as above. This is a contradiction. Thus, there is no $x \in A \cap (X \backslash A)$; i.e. $A \cap (X \backslash A) = \emptyset$.

Comment: Also, this book is my first purely rigorous maths text so my confusion with logic should be even bigger than that of someone who has taken a preliminary course in proofs and logic. When looking at answers on different questions I on MathSE I saw people using logic symbols and that's what made me read a bit more into them and Boolean Algebras.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147549/discussion-between-prometheus-and-eric).

Comment: Not to overcrowd the comments because my last one went off-topic so this will be my last; I agree with your proof and understand it. If someone can confirm if my proof of that makes sense then I'd be interested in that.